# Slicing pandas dataframe by column numbers I don't want

Tags: python, pandas

I'm coming from the R world, where the `df[,-c(1,7)]` function works nicely to select everything but the noncontiguous column numbers (in this case, all but columns 1 and 7) from the data frame.

I'm trying to do the same thing in Pandas.

Here's a dummy dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10), 'b':range(10,20), 'c':list('abcdefghij'), 'g':[1]*3 + [2]*3 + [3]*4, 'f':[1]*3 + [2]*3 + [3]*4, 'j':[1]*3 + [2]*3 + [3]*4})

df1
   a   b  c  f  g  j
0  0  10  a  1  1  1
1  1  11  b  1  1  1
2  2  12  c  1  1  1
3  3  13  d  2  2  2
4  4  14  e  2  2  2
5  5  15  f  2  2  2
6  6  16  g  3  3  3
7  7  17  h  3  3  3
8  8  18  i  3  3  3
9  9  19  j  3  3  3
```

I know I can do the below, which selects the columns I want (rather than omitting what I don't want):

```
df1[list(df1.columns[0:2]) + list(df1.columns[4:6])]

   a   b  g  j
0  0  10  1  1
1  1  11  1  1
2  2  12  1  1
3  3  13  2  2
4  4  14  2  2
5  5  15  2  2
6  6  16  3  3
7  7  17  3  3
8  8  18  3  3
9  9  19  3  3
```

but is there a way to tell Pandas that I want everything except columns 2 and 3? And, can we extend this to say I want everything except columns 2 and 4?  And everything except 0:2 and 4?

Comment: Also, I want to avoid having to use column names (as compared to numbers) as the actual column names are quite verbose and a pain to type.

Comment: how about "del df1[df1.columns[2],df1.columns[4]]"?

Comment: You could index into `columns` and use `drop`, e.g. `df2 = df1.drop(df1.columns[[2,3]],axis=1)`, but I wonder if there's a cleaner way.. hmm.

Comment: Another interesting option, but yes, I wonder if there's anything built into Pandas that would do this more concisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [9]: df1.iloc[:,~pd.Int64Index(np.arange(len(df1.columns))).isin([2,4])]
Out[9]: 
   a   b  f  j
0  0  10  1  1
1  1  11  1  1
2  2  12  1  1
3  3  13  2  2
4  4  14  2  2
5  5  15  2  2
6  6  16  3  3
7  7  17  3  3
8  8  18  3  3
9  9  19  3  3

[10 rows x 4 columns]
```

Can be a bit cleaner with this:

```
In [10]: ic = lambda x: pd.Int64Index(np.arange(x))

In [11]: df1.iloc[:,~ic(len(df1.columns)).isin([2,4])]
Out[11]: 
   a   b  f  j
0  0  10  1  1
1  1  11  1  1
2  2  12  1  1
3  3  13  2  2
4  4  14  2  2
5  5  15  2  2
6  6  16  3  3
7  7  17  3  3
8  8  18  3  3
9  9  19  3  3

[10 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I also make slices of what I don't want, ie have `isin([0:3, 4])`?

Comment: yes, you could use ``np.r_[0:3,4]`` (which returns an array, and can be used instead of a list inside the isin)

Comment: yep, awesome, `df1.iloc[:,~ic(len(df1.columns)).isin(np.r_[0:3,4])]` works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

well one way is to use `np.r_` from `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
df2 = df[np.r_[0, 2, 4:]]
```

another approach is to do something like:

```
df2 = df[np.delete(np.arange(len(df.columns)), (2, 7))]
```

Comment: that makes sense, but I'm looking at a way to explicitly exclude columns from the dataframe, not just select around them.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Also, can I make slices of what I don't want, like 0:3 and 7?